# MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

Tags: mongodb, localhost, mean-stack

I have paid a membership and downloaded [this project](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack). After `npm install` and `node app.js`, it returns the following error:

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
/Users/Thomas/Desktop/mean-stack-tutorial-01$ node app.js 

/Users/Thomas/Desktop/mean-stack-tutorial-01/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/Thomas/Desktop/mean-stack-tutorial-01/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/Thomas/Desktop/mean-stack-tutorial-01/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Thomas/Desktop/mean-stack-tutorial-01/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:173:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**Edit 1:** Following the comments, I just installed mongo via `brew`, and did `brew services start mongodb` and then `mongo`:

```
/Users/Thomas$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-01-12T19:53:01.868+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-01-12T19:53:01.869+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-01-12T19:53:01.869+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-01-12T19:53:01.869+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Then I did

```
/Users/Thomas$ mongod -httpinterface --dbpath /Users/Thomas/Desktop/MongoDB/db
2017-01-12T20:14:05.620+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=47356 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/Thomas/Desktop/MongoDB/db 64-bit host=Pro.local
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-01-12T20:14:05.621+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/Users/Thomas/Desktop/MongoDB/db" } }
2017-01-12T20:14:05.657+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-01-12T20:14:14.108+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-01-12T20:14:14.108+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-01-12T20:14:14.108+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-01-12T20:14:14.108+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-01-12T20:14:14.108+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-01-12T20:14:14.109+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2017-01-12T20:14:15.390+0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/Users/Thomas/Desktop/MongoDB/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-01-12T20:14:16.303+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2017-01-12T20:14:16.304+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2017-01-12T20:14:16.406+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2017-01-12T20:14:16.407+0800 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2017-01-12T20:14:16.407+0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Then in another terminal, I did `node app.js`, which hangs (and does not print anything). Then I does `http://localhost:28017` in a browser, it seems to work:

[image]

However, how could I see the website?

**Edit 2:**

The normal process is

1. install mongo
2. `brew services start mongodb` in a terminal
3. `mongo &` (assume we use the default folder `/data/db/`)
4. `npm start`
5. see e.g., `bin/www` for the port number, then use `localhost:the_port_number` in a browser

Comment: is MongoDB server running ?

Comment: mine solved by giving  folder data/db read and write persmission

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update 2020 Feb 24:**

It would be wise to stay tuned with it. Here is the link for latest library instruction:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/

---

You haven't started your monogo database. first install mongo [install mongo as per your OS https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/)

then follow instructions mentioned on this site:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/

1. cd .
2. mongod --dbpath "any directory path to start your database "

and then start your node server. It will work fine.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

First open another terminal an run command `mongod` to start your mongoDB

Then again start you node server `npm start` or if you have "nodemon" then using `nodemon`

I think now everything will be fine it will show

```
Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/your_database
```

Comment: Please respect how the posts should be formatted. Especially when someone does it for you.

Comment: @Matyas you misinterpreted me. I have modified my answer to the edit suggested by you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but it worked fine after restarting the service

`service mongod start`

Answer (score 0):

Incase none of these helped, mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/ worked for me instead of localhost.