# mongo: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

[image: happened to someone?]

what can I do to solve this problem? I'm on windows so I can't run sudo mongo I tried to do "runas" in windows instead of linux "sudo" but it didn;t help me out. I was looking for a fle called monogod.lock to remove it but didn't find something like that...I tried mongo repair but it also didn't help me...help someone?

btw...I tried to start mongo.exe from it's directory in another CMD but it failed also:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have not started the Mongo DB Server.
Do the followings.

1. In **Windows**, start **Command Prompt**.
2. Run **mongod.exe** to start Mongo DB Server.(This will work only if your environment variable **PATH** contains the ***bin*** directory of your Mongo DB installation)
3. Open another **Command Prompt** and start client by running **mongo.exe**.

Check this link which might help you.

[MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611146/mongoerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connect?rq=1)

Comment: yea just that it's fail to connect to mongo while I'm trying to run on windows in mongo directory mongo.exe ... =[ I'm adding the picture to my question

Answer (score 0):

oh guys I finally got that! when you run mongod.exe on windows you should also give it the path of the directory if not it won't work! if somehow you'll have a mongod.lock on your directory you should delete this file than write on CMD mongod.exe repair and start running it again! thanks to all =]

Answer (score 0):

## In linux

1.- In the terminal

$ sudo systemctl start mongodb

$ mongo

Comment: there is already an answer which is selected, and other is OP's own (saying by doing that he has solved issue). Does your answer support these answer !? Or is it carries anything extra OP should keep in mind.?